# Explicit worked example of symmetrizing system of conservation laws

Tags: partial-differential-equations, entropy, hyperbolic-equations

Pg 4 of [this book](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-1-4612-1116-7) gives the Euler equations for an ideal gas in the variables $(p, \textbf{v}, S)$ read:
$$\frac{Dp}{Dt} + \gamma p \, \text{div} \textbf{v} = 0$$
$$\rho \frac{D\textbf{v}}{Dt} + \nabla p = 0$$
$$\frac{DS}{Dt} = 0$$
Here, $\frac{D}{Dt}$ is the material derivative and $\rho$ is a function of $S$ and $p$. The author of the comment in the second answer in this [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3951322/symmetrizability-of-conservation-laws-via-mathematical-entropy/3977259) discusses how to express the foregoing system of conservations laws in matrix form and have this matrix be symmetric. According the pg 9 of [this book](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-1-4612-1116-7), multiplying the foregoing system by the diagonal 5 by 5 matrix
$$A = 
\begin{bmatrix}
(\gamma p )^{-1} &  & \\
 & \rho(p,S) \textbf{I}_3 & \\
 & & 1
\end{bmatrix}
$$
gives a symmetric coefficient matrix outlined in the spirit of the comments in the second answer on the [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3951322/symmetrizability-of-conservation-laws-via-mathematical-entropy/3977259) above. In particular, my understanding is that the system of conservation laws should have the form:

$$A\textbf{z}_t + A\,\text{div}\,\textbf{F}(\textbf{z}) = 0$$

where $\textbf{z} = (p, u, v, w, S)$ (the components of velocity are given by $u, v, w$ here). I'm having trouble expressing second term in component form so that I can see an explicit example of the symmetric matrix discussed in the post above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To see an explicit example it would help to write out the system
as follows. It is almost symmetric already, because it reads
$$
\begin{bmatrix} 1 &  0   & 0    & 0    & 0 \\
                0 & \rho & 0    & 0    & 0 \\
                0 &  0   & \rho & 0    & 0 \\
                0 &  0   &   0  & \rho & 0 \\
                0 &  0   &   0  & 0    & 1 \end{bmatrix}z_t
+
\begin{bmatrix} v_1 & \gamma p & 0        & 0        & 0 \\
                1   & \rho v_1 & 0        & 0        & 0 \\
                0   &  0       & \rho v_1 & 0        & 0 \\
                0   &  0       & 0        & \rho v_1 & 0 \\
                0   &  0       & 0        & 0        & v_1\end{bmatrix}z_{x_1}
 $$ $$
+
\begin{bmatrix} v_2 &  0       & \gamma p & 0      & 0 \\
                0   & \rho v_2 & 0        & 0        & 0 \\
                1   &  0       & \rho v_2 & 0        & 0 \\
                0   &  0       & 0        & \rho v_2 & 0 \\
                0   &  0       & 0        & 0        & v_2\end{bmatrix}z_{x_2}
+
\begin{bmatrix} v_3 &  0       & 0        & \gamma p & 0 \\
                0   & \rho v_3 & 0        & 0        & 0 \\
                0   &  0       & \rho v_3 & 0        & 0 \\
                1   &  0       & 0        & \rho v_3 & 0 \\
                0   &  0       & 0        & 0        & v_3\end{bmatrix}z_{x_3}
 = 0.
$$
It is only necessary to multiply the first line by
$(\gamma p)^{-1}$ to make the coefficient matrices symmetric.